# Pass updated parent state to child props React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have two child components in my parent component with routing set up. Child1 component's button updates state of the parent component and I want to pass the updated version of that state to  child2 component as props. The problem is, although the state obviously updates in the parent component(I checked it), it doesn't get passed to the child2 component(the older version of state gets passed instead). I think it's because the `getdData` function(in the parent component) executes after the child2 component gets rendered. How can I solve this issue so that correct state gets passed?

Here's the code:

Parent component:

```
import './App.css';
import Questions from './components/questions';
import DropDownDifficulty from './components/dropDownDifficulty';
import {useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  
  const [data, setdata] = useState([])
  const getdData = (values)=>{
    setdata(values)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Route exact path='/'>
          <DropDownDifficulty sendData={getdData}/>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path = '/quiz'>
          <Questions specs={data}/>
        </Route>
      
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Child1 component's button:

```
<Button  disabled={buttonDisabled} className='button' variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={()=>sendData([category, Difficulty])}>
            Start Quiz
        </Button>
```

child2 component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Question from './question'


export default function Questions({specs}) {
    console.log(specs)
    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Solution :

1.Check for Correct value before passing it down to props

```
<div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Route exact path='/'>
          <DropDownDifficulty sendData={getdData}/>
        </Route>
        {data?.length > 0 && <Route exact path = '/quiz'>
          <Questions specs={data}/>
        </Route>}
      </Router>
    </div>
```

2. You can use useEffect and listen to props and show value only after the correct data comes

```
import {useEffect} from 'react'
import Question from './question'


export default function Questions({specs}) {
    const [showIfCorrect,setShowIfCorrect]=useState(false)
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(specs){
          // Check if it is correct
          setShowIfCorrect(true)
         }
    },[specs])
    return (
        <div>
          {showIfCorrect && <div>Correct Question</div>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

3. use Context Api and update state from sibling component(DropDownDifficulty) and pass it to the Questions component

For How to implement in context api refer the code below
[image: Edit nervous-wing-6f3nd]

Comment: Unfortunately, 1st and 2nd solutions didn't work for me. In the first solution Questions was never rendered, as for second solution, specs never updated and it was just an empty array. Can you post the entire code if you got this working? Thanks!

Comment: It will take some time,I got the issue which you are facing , It is because of React Router , I will do it after 8 hours , I will share codesandbox, need to sleep

Comment: Hi  bearthum , did you found the solution or you want me to help you here

Comment: No, I didn't find the solution. Your help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the answer with context api , please refer to that

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! The solution you provided works as I wanted. There are some concepts that I don't quite understand in the solution but I'll work my way out and learn them. Thank you again!

Comment: Please accept the answer if you find it helpful and it solved your issue